# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I was making some changes to the template after restarting the ng server. I started getting error in console. I reverted the working code back but its still throwing the same error. I'm finding it very difficult to debug this error because it's not pointing to a template file. I'm using angular cli. There are 2 errors displayed in the console:

**Error1:**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
>       at splitDepsDsl (core.es5.js:8712)
>       at _def (core.es5.js:10695)
>       at directiveDef (core.es5.js:10652)
>       at View_AppComponent_Host_0 (AppComponent_Host.html:1)
>       at proxyClass (compiler.es5.js:14971)
>       at resolveDefinition (core.es5.js:8756)
>       at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9859)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
>       at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4768)
>       at core.es5.js:4546

**Error 2:**

> zone.js:661 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'map' of null ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
>       at splitDepsDsl (core.es5.js:8712)
>       at _def (core.es5.js:10695)
>       at directiveDef (core.es5.js:10652)
>       at View_AppComponent_Host_0 (AppComponent_Host.html:1)
>       at proxyClass (compiler.es5.js:14971)
>       at resolveDefinition (core.es5.js:8756)
>       at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9859)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
>       at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4768)
>       at core.es5.js:4546 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
>       at splitDepsDsl (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:100930:17)
>       at _def (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102913:36)
>       at directiveDef (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102870:12)
>       at View_AppComponent_Host_0 (ng:///AppModule/AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:6:67)
>       at proxyClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:79342:29)
>       at resolveDefinition (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:100974:17)
>       at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:102077:40)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:95551:29)
>       at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96986:57)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96764:81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to broken package in angular. I ran `yarn upgrade` command which fixed the issue.

Comment: I tried yarn upgrade but didn't work for me.